# NLTK reverse n-gram search

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a corpus that consists of various messages. I used NLTK to create a series of bi-grams and tri-grams. I created the grams by doing pre-processing like removing stop words and things of the sort.

How can I take a bi-gram (or tri) and search to see if it exists in a new message? I would have to pre-process the message at some point wouldn't I?

Or, if I can do this another way, during the creation of the n-gram process, is it possible to index the messages and output both the n-grams and which message they apply to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to creating n-grams sounds like a great start! Removing the stop words, normalizing text formatting (removing punctuation, replacing two spaces with one, etc.) are all important preprocessing steps when creating your n-grams. And, yep, you're right: if you're going to try to look for your n-gram in a new message you're going to have to preprocess that new message in the same way that you preprocessed your other data by removing the stop words, etc. and then generating the n-grams for that new message.

If you have a lot of n-grams (and even if you don't for this project, it's still a good practice to get into), try creating a matrix of all of your n-grams. For each document (message, in your case) list out all of your n-grams that you've initially found in your data. If the specified n-gram occurs in that particular document assign it a value of 1. For n-grams that don't occur in that document, assign that particular n-gram a score of 0:

[image: document and term vector matrix]

Given that you may have A LOT of n-grams (especially if the messages are long) you may want to look into something like [term frequency inverse-document frequency, or `tf-idf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to help you discover / weight rarer terms more heavily than more common terms. Like you noted by removing stop words from your data, commonly-occuring terms like 'the', 'and', 'a', etc. (which we call 'low information tokens' or low-information words in Information Theory) don't really tell us much about the document at hand, its main topic, nor does the presence of words like 'the', 'and', 'a' allow us to disambiguate DocumentA from DocumentB (because most documents have words like 'the', 'and', 'a', in them.

This free book [Introduction to Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/index-construction-1.html) has a few chapters on index construction and index compression that might be of use as you explore building and querying indices. If you're from a math background and linear algebra is something that's familiar to you I'd recommend another book by the same authors called [The Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/) which covers a lot of the same material as the IR textbook, but it provides a much more thorough mathematical background to the material covered in the IR textbook.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I'm definitely going down this road.